# Adding external files to ClickOnce VSTO deployment

Tags: vsto, clickonce

I need to deploy a PowerPoint presentation (.pptx) together with my VSTO project (and be able to open it) via ClickOnce. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: please explain your scenario..

Answer (score 0):

As far as my take on your question.. Below given are the steps to do.
Right click on project--> Add Existing Item... -> Add your file
Later check on Project Properties --> Publish Tab --> Application Files... -->Check whether your ppt is listed there.

If yes, then your click once deployment will install along with this ppt file will be present in executing path.